# Excel How to find more values that contain values in the cell next to them?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I want to use the Index formula to list data in my excel sheet.
I want to list the data of the column A that contains "finished" in the corresponding cells in column E.

Currently I'm using the following formula:

=INDEX(IMs!A:A;MATCH("finished";IMs!E:E;0))

The problem is, only the first value appears. I want to list ALL of them.
Is it possible with the vlookup formula?

Thank you very much in advance.

Kind regards,
Vanessa

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The problem is, I want to list the cells (with the value "finished" in the cell next to it) in another sheet, not in the same one. I don't want to edit the sheet with the values, only the one where I want to have my results. Do you know how to do this? @pnuts

Comment: I would like to have it dynamically. When I add values in the other sheet, I want the cells to appear automatically. Not possible? @pnuts

Comment: This might be of interest/use:http://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/11/29/lookup-and-return-multiple-values-from-a-range-excluding-blanks/

Comment: I don't think that fits to my question. But thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First enter this formula in B1:

=COUNTIF(IMs!$E:$E,"Finished")

Then enter this **array formula**** in your first cell of choice:

=IF(ROWS($1:1)>$B$1,"",INDEX(IMs!$A$1:$A$1000,SMALL(IF(IMs!$E$1:$E$1000="finished",ROW(IMs!$E$1:$E$1000)-MIN(ROW(IMs!$E$1:$E$1000))+1),ROWS($1:1))))

Copy this formula down (though not the one in C1) until you start to get blanks for the results.

If the upper row reference that I chose (1000) is not sufficiently high, then change it as required. Note, however, that since this is an array formula, it is not recommended that you make this upper bound *too* high (and certainly don't reference entire columns!), since this will have a significantly detrimental effect on spreadsheet performance.

From your post, it also appears that you are using a version of Excel in which the argument separator in formulas is not the comma but the semi-colon. If this is indeed the case then you will need to make the necessary amendments to the formulas I provided.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I don't really understand the formula. I've put the first formula in B1 with the Count-if-formula. The number 30 appeared, which means I have 30 cells with "finished". When I put the If....-fomula in the cell below, I have only a blank cell. I also tried it with the CTRL and SHIFT and Enter, and the curly brackets appear. Though not the results appear. I want to have the 30 cells as a list, where I have finished in the cell in the column E. Can you see my mistake? 
@XOR LX